# How to have the exact input time of row B1 in A1

Tags: excel

is there is any formula to have the input time of B1 in A1..
or in row A1 how to get the exact time of input of B1..
.is it possible by excel formula

Comment: or is it been possible with any macro?

Answer (score 1):

Dont know any way to do it with formulas, but you can use the worksheet change event like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 Then ' did a value in column B change?
 Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Now ' write date and time in column A
End If
End Sub
```